# 'Cannot read property 'lastChild' of null' How to do if the node does not yet exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nodes

I can not delete this error:

```
mypage.php:53 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lastChild' of null
```

That is generated by this code:

```
var textNode = document.getElementById('element');
if(textNode.lastChild.lastChild.nodeName === 'BUTTON'){
```

The error is normal, because it has not yet been generated. var textNode still does not contain the code.

*This node still does not exist: how can I do to say: if the node does not exist ...?*

I would like to suppress the warning by saying that 'if there is textNode.lastChild.lastChild', but any attempt is made in this error, or I read the text: is null.
Since the error blocks the script, I would simply like it: if it does run, if it does not exist ignore it.

Edit:
Thanks to your answers I solved. I do not point to the solution because you both put the solution.

Answer (score 1):

> I would simply like it: if it does run, if it does not exist ignore it.

In this case you need to check that the `textNode` and first `lastChild` property returns something, which you can do like this:

```
var textNode = document.getElementById('element');
if (textNode && textNode.lastChild && textNode.lastChild.lastChild.nodeName === 'BUTTON') {
  console.log('The button exists!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> how can I do to say: if the node does not exist

Check if it was found before trying to use it:

```
var textNode = document.getElementById('element');
if (textNode) {
  if(textNode.lastChild.lastChild.nodeName === 'BUTTON') {
    //...
  }
}
```

or even:

```
var textNode = document.getElementById('element');
if (textNode && textNode.lastChild.lastChild.nodeName === 'BUTTON') {
    //...
}
```

Or is it the nested `lastChild`?  Something like this:

```
var textNode = document.getElementById('element');
if (textNode && textNode.lastChild && textNode.lastChild.lastChild.nodeName === 'BUTTON') {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me!